# Higcharts: how to render background text over the chart, when there are plotBand with different colors?

Tags: highcharts

I have this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/c1Luhysm/) where I have text rendered at the background of the chart and also a plotBand with a different background color.

The text in the background is rendered with:

```
 this.renderer.text('This text is <span style="color: rgb(255,0,0)">styled</span>!!!', 50, 150)
   .css({
     color: 'rgb(0,0,255)',
     fontSize: '40px'
   }).add();
```

While the plotBand is configured as:

```
  xAxis: {
    plotBands: [{ // mark the weekend
      color: 'rgb(0,255,0)',//'rgba(0,255,0,0.5)',
      from: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2),
      to: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 4),
      label: {
        text: 'Plot band',
        align: 'right',
        x: -10
      }
    }],
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
    type: 'datetime'
  },
```

In the result that I got, we can see how the plotBand goes above the background text, and this is something that I need to avoid. I need my background text to be fully visible in front of this plotBand.

[image]

As a workaround, I tied setting up the opacity the plot background color like `color: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.5)'`, but this did not help, as the colors are interfering and it is noticeable that background text is not in front of the plotBand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `toFront` method which is built in the SVGElement's.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vj51kogm/

```
 function() {
  let text = this.renderer.text('This text is <span style="color: rgb(255,0,0)">styled</span>!!!', 50, 150)
    .css({
      color: 'rgb(0,0,255)',
      fontSize: '40px',
    }).add();
        
    text.toFront()
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#toFront

Comment: and how about this case: https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/bernaw6h/2/ please check how the text now goes in front of the area chart as well. Can we set the area chart itself to go in front of the text?

Comment: In this scenario, I think that we need to set the zIndex which value will be higher than the `plotBand` z-index but lower than the area path. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g69n1d5t/